# You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

I am new to android development. recently i have uploaded my app to playstore and couldnt download it from there because i faced this issue "your device isnt compatible with this version". on further analysis I could found out that I have used feature "android.hardware.type.watch" along with android.hardware.faketouch, android.hardware.telephony. which is why i could see only watch devices in supported devices list on console (this was mistakenly ignored during rollout).

now to correct this mistake, I have removed watch feature, built apk with incremented version code. I need to replace live app on playstore with newly built apk. I have used 2 methods ( creating release in production and creating beta release )but everytime I am facing below issue "You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs.

i tried many time by increasing version code from 3 to 40 but same error is occur please help me

Comment: Did you contact Google for this issue? I am also facing the same. Please post updates if any

Comment: I wrote mail to help support, and waiting for since 2 days still no reply...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distribute android phone+wearOS projects in same play console store listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610086/how-to-distribute-android-phonewearos-projects-in-same-play-console-store-listi)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened because I accidently added **android wear** support.
Removing the following line in the **manifest** solved my problem

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- Lets go in detail,  Firstly as new developer i confused between Empty
  Activity and Blank Activity in android while creating Activity.
  Well
  in my case i choose blank activity instead empty activity, then in
  blank activity i get some watch and wear dependency in gradle file as
  **implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'** and in manifest file

### <meta-dataandroid:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalon android:value="true"/>

---

### **`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`**

If you publish this apk file or app bundle then you will get error as

**Your device is not compatible with this version**

Then i read it some where..

Your android project you have 2 apps:

1.Mobile 2.Wearable

Mobile app should be installed on mobile device (phone/tablet) and Wearable app should be installed on Android Wear device.

This message No, missing feature: WATCH means that you're trying to install Wearable app on mobile phone - you shouldn't do that, your mobile device is not a WATCH. So once again: just launch Mobile app on mobile and Wearable app on Android Wear.

After this i remove the line from manifest

### **`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`**

And upload again to the google play console then i got new error as

### You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs

if i add this line again in manifest file then this error is gone and old error is come

### Your device is not compatible with this version

### Solution:

---

Create new application in google play console with different package name and make your change your package name in gradle file and all over.
and remove all dependencies related to watch n wear and remove line from manifest file

1. <meta-dataandroid:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalon android:value="true"/
2. **`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />`**

And publish again and check compatible device that your app is support before rollout , after publish you will get mail from google as report of tested application.

Comment: Publish as a new App doesn't sound good. Have you contacted google for this issue? I think these issues can be fixed by them.

Comment: Remove this line from manifest then you will not get error as "You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs" <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />"/

Comment: Removing the watch dependency wont be solving the issue if any releases already available in production with watch dependency.