# Internal testing release for android Wear App

Tags: android, wear-os, google-play-console, android-wear-2.0, google-play-internal-testing

I'm facing an issue while trying to upload an internal testing release for an Android Wear App on Google Play Console

I get the following error: **You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added app bundles.**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndr6F.png)

I've tried uploading both modules (app and wear app) while having the same version code and I've tried uploading them using different version codes too.

Wear Module Manafist

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />
    
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="false" />
```

App Module Manafist

```
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.JPUSH_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <service
        android:name=".service.AppIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>
```

Without `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />` in the app module, then if I added this in the app module the build works fine but the app APK installed on the watch

Does anyone have the same issue? any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distribute android phone+wearOS projects in same play console store listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610086/how-to-distribute-android-phonewearos-projects-in-same-play-console-store-listi)

Comment: @Devedse i fix the issue by adding 2 aab one for mobile and one for wear with different version code for each

Comment: So if you do an update, do you up both version codes? E.g. you currently have Android: 100 and WearOS: 101. If you do an update you go to Android: 102 and WearOS: 103?